Excel Text Translate function without API on MacOS
I have been trying to create a formula in excel using VBA to translate text from a cell to another language (e.g. "=TextTranslate(Text, sourceLanguage, targetLanguage)").
I have found a way to achieve this on windows using this method and this method. Neither are working on Mac though. I'm new to VBA so my knowledge is limited but I figured something could be done using curl (???). Does anyone know of a way I can achieve similar results on MacOs?

Can you clarify what you mean by without API? You can indeed accomplish this by invoking cURL using libc.dylib - for example.

Thank you for the answer, I'll look into the post. From research I figured the most popular option for this would be to use Google Translation API or Microsoft Azure API services for the translation.
